# libgdx - how to achieve frozen object effect

Tags: libgdx

I want to achieve the effect of some object being frozen
For example something like this:

This is normal - no effect:
[image]

And this is with effect:
[image]

I thought that maybe i could do it with color tint on sprite batch, but it doesn't work since white is default color for tint in sprite batch

Comment: How about using a very light shade of gray instead of white?

Comment: how about sprite.setcolor(Color.white);
please ignore syntax here

Comment: nice graphics though

Comment: @A.Visser nope, it just appears darker.

Comment: @Kumar Saurabh white is default color for tint, that will do nothing

Comment: my friend i asked to change color of sprite not changing tint of sprite batch

Comment: you are having a sprite object or texture or texture region?

Comment: isn't that the same?, and anyway i'm not using sprite, i'm using Texture/TextureRegion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88165/discussion-between-kumar-saurabh-and-pedja).

Comment: If you don't want to create a white version of your sprite, you need a specialized shader for that. Copy the one out of SpriteBatch's source code and add a line at the bottom of the fragment shader's function to blend towards white. `gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(gl_FragColor.rgb, vec3(1.0), 0.7);`

Comment: @Tenfour04 that kind of works, but only if alpha of tint color is 1f, fully opaque, i need that object to slowly fade back to normal. The effect should be similar to Photoshops "Normal Blend" with Color Overlay.

Comment: But that is a different problem, i will create new question. Thanks anyway

Comment: follow-up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275318/glsl-shader-color-blend-normal-mode-like-in-photoshop

Comment: you have really nice graphics, I wouldn't spoil it with using just spraying colors on the texture. If you don't need to give this effect to every object, I would go for original texture with frozen monster. Means: Photoshop

Comment: @pedja what does the alpha of the tint color have to do with it? If you are not using one of the rgb channels of the sprite's vertex color, you could use one of them for the last parameter in the mix function to get a gradual blend. Or since you're probably only drawing a few frozen objects, you could store it in a uniform.

Comment: @Tenfour04 if alpha is not 1, then whole object is semi-transparent

Comment: You must not be using the code I posted, which has no alpha. The color you're blending toward is `vec3(1.0)` which is white with no alpha.

Comment: this is in the fragments main function: `gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
  gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(gl_FragColor.rgb, vec3(1.0), 0.7);`

Comment: tint color on SpriteBatch is (1, 1, 1, .5f)

Comment: omg, i got it: `gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
  gl_FragColor.rgb = mix(gl_FragColor.rgb, vec3(1.0), v_color.a);`. You put me on the right track. Thanks

Comment: @Tenfour04 write an answer with this, i will accept it, if you want

Comment: here is a simple solution
in your render do  this
GLCommon gl = Gdx.gl;
  gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0.1f);
  gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
sprite.setColor(Color.CLEAR);

Comment: @KumarSaurabh already found the solution, but thanks anyway